# onclick function is called even without clicking the button

Tags: javascript

so I have a small html renderer, that returns a div with h1 and button tags nested in it.

```
for(let each in infoForThatDay) {
        if(infoForThatDay[each]['start'] == hour.substring(0, 2)) {
            let htmlRender = `
                 <div class='flex-boxes'>
                 <h1>${infoForThatDay[each]['title']}</h1>
                 <button onclick="${console.log('at least it works until here')}">დაჯავშნე ახლა</button>
                 </div>
             `;
             html += htmlRender;
        }
    };
    let wrapper = document.querySelector('.users');
    wrapper.innerHTML = html;
```

the 'at least it works until here' is logged once for all the elements in infoForThatDay.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance <3

Comment: also nothing happens when i actually click the button

Comment: Take a step back and look at what you're doing.  You're constructing a **string** called `htmlRender`.  You used a template (a.k.a. string interpolation) to build that string.  You're placing the output of a function into that string.  The function you called is console.log.  That will _return_ undefined. (expect to see `undefined` embedded in your string)  As a side effect it will also log to the console.  Your approach should rather be that onclick should call a function.

Comment: Whatever you wrap inside template strings' `${}` gets evaluated at the time it gets parsed. Just remove `${` and `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not put the statement inside `onclick` attribute in `${}`, since you are doing it, it executes as part of your JS function. Your code should be this

```
let htmlRender = `
                 <div class='flex-boxes'>
                 <h1>${infoForThatDay[each]['title']}</h1>
                 <button onclick="console.log('at least it works until here')">დაჯავშნე ახლა</button>
                 </div>
             `;
```

The `console.log` code gets printed as a string to the HTML you are rendering, and not executed as soon as your code is run.